# $SU(N)$ gauge theory in black hole background

Tags: black-holes, gauge-theory, quantum-chromodynamics, qft-in-curved-spacetime

Assume you have standard $SU(N)$ gauge theory in a (non-asymptotically flat) black hole background (i.e., near the center of the black hole).

Given the extreme pressure and temperature, I assume that under certain conditions asymptotic freedom holds and that locally the conditions are similar to what one has e.g. at CERN.

***Is this somewhat vague argument reasonable?***

Given that the $S$-matrix for such a theory is not defined there, unlike CERN, what does one hope to understand about QCD in a such curved background? For example can something like correlation functions defined?

This is motivated by the paper arXiv: [1405.6665 [hep-lat]](https://arxiv.org/abs/1405.6665), "Lattice QCD on curved spacetime". However, in low energies, I do not see why the curved background one would expect lattice QCD to behave differently in a classical but curved background.

I understand the question is not a specific quantitative one, but some comments or tips can provide a lot of intuition.

Comment: Why the restriction to a non asymptotically flat background black hole? This seems like an unnecessary complication.

Comment: Are you aware that even free scalar fields behave wildly different in curved spacetime? For example, giving raise to [Hawking radiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawking_temperature)?

Comment: I also don't find clear why the "extreme pressure and temperature". Even once one considers the temperature coming from Hawking radiation, typical black holes are quite cold. Classical black holes would at $0$ K, since they can't be in thermal equilibrium with anything at a higher temperature.

Comment: I think that the main interest  here is in investigating how the curved background can affect the potential between quarks. Maybe this article will also be helpful: [Lattice gauge theory and gluon color-confinement in curved spacetime](https://arxiv.org/abs/1407.1371v3)